# Windows 7 install troubleshooting

Tags: windows-7

I'm installing a fresh new 7 x64 on a brand new computer. Install goes fine, until the first reboot, then:

1. it says "setup is now updating registry settings" for a few seconds
2. computer automaticall reboots
3. on reboot it says: Boot from CD/DVD-rom:
4. It just hangs there (it never says: press any key to boot from CD/DVD ... )

I suspected a faulty DVD so I burned a second one. Identical behaviour.

Is there any way for me to get some sort of "Installation Log" perhaps to read through some errors durring installation? All I get is a reboot with not much left to troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

Err... is the bios set to boot from the drive you installed windows7 on? After you've installed win7 you don't need to leave the cd in there and it hence shouldn't be trying to boot from CD sooo it shouldn't be hanging. Go into the bios and check that boot order has the HDD on there.

Comment: BIOS is set to boot from CD first time.. then it boots from HDD the second time... then reboots unexpectedly.. then hangs before the "pres any key  to boot from CD"..no changes to BIOS between the boots

Comment: you don't need the CD/DVD AFTER you copy the windows files over... it will install on its own. Should install WITHOUT the cd.